# I am getting an error while saving data to csv

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I am trying to save data from multiple website to csv using selenium

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/trive/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
templist = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    driver.get(data._get_value(i,'URL'))
    
    try:
        title= driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "amp-wp-title").text  
        content= driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "amp-wp-article-content").text 
      
        Table_dict={ 'Title': title,
                    'Content':content}
      
        templist.append(Table_dict) 
        df = pd.DataFrame(templist)
   

    except NoSuchElementException: 
        continue


# saving the dataframe to a csv
df.to_csv('S:/DEADPOOL/black coffr assignment/table.csv')
driver.close()
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
 NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-18-8534ce45b80d> in <module>
 ---> 28 print(df)

 NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

I think it is to do with df only existing in the for loop and not outside but i don't know how to solve this.

Comment: move the `df.to_csv('S:/DEADPOOL/black coffr assignment/table.csv')` in the `try` block, else `df` is undefined when you have an exception.

Comment: It's good practice to review error stacktraces, rather than just ignoring them ,like you do in your try/except block. Also, if you could post the url of the page you are trying to scrape, you would get a more illuminating answer.

Comment: I am reading in a list of URLs from an excel file and saving the article title and content to a csv file. My question is if i put it in the try block won't it convert that data frame to csv on every single iteration? Would that cause an error or will it just append the data to the file created in the first iteration. @mozway

Answer (score 2):

In your `for` loop you have a `try/except` clause, where the `except` clause just does `continue`. I suspect there's an error somewhere in the try section preventing the creation of the dataframe `df`

In other words, this line

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(templist)
```

probably never gets executed as it is skipped due to an error that is always being caught by

```py
except NoSuchElementException
```

Another thing to note is that this line

```py
df.to_csv('S:/DEADPOOL/black coffr assignment/table.csv')
```

is being run outside the loop, which means it will only be executed once after the loop ends, so only the last iteration of `df = pd.DataFrame(templist)` would matter if it actually did run without errors.